# How auth in linux with google account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google

I'm setting up Ubuntu 18.04, and trying the Ubuntu auth users with Google accounts from my G Suite. That's the idea, but after search about that, I can't find much information for this. Any ideas?.

Answer (score 3):

There's a PAM module for google Authentication.
On your system the following command shows the package details.

```
$ apt show libpam-google-authenticator
```

You can read about it at Github here:

https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam

Comment: I read about that, but this module, If I understand it, set a second factor auth, not work for auth with google account.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is centralised authentication, something like LDAP.

If you use a tool like [Okta](https://www.okta.com/partners/gsuite/), you can indirectly [tie GSuite to AD](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en) (or an LDAP server). And then of course you can [tie OpenSSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/23632/how-to-use-active-directory-to-authenticate-linux-users) there as well.

Comment: Thanks, in my work, we have LDAP, and the G-Suite authenticate with LDAP, linux too, but my idea, If is possible, was authenticate with the google account, for example, the user login in linux with username@mydomain.com and password in the LDAP.